# C language If statement

Tags: c

I am new to C language and trying to figure out the meaning of the following code.

In here `if (!msize)` checking to see if `msize` is zero or if `msize` is NULL ?

```
if (!msize)
    msize = 1 / msize; /* provoke a signal */

//Example 1: A division-by-zero misuse, in lib/mpi/mpi-pow.c of the Linux kernel, where the entire code will be optimized away. 
//Compilers, GCC 4.7 and Clang 3.1
```

Comment: There is no difference between 0 and NULL in most systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of `msize`.

- If `msize` is a pointer, it tests whether it is `NULL`.
- If `msize` is not a pointer, it tests whether it is `0`.

This distinction may seem pedantic, but it's important.  While `NULL` is actually `0` on most systems, the C standard allows it to be any other value.

---

I did some further reading, because I started to doubt whether my understanding above is correct.

Here are relevant parts of the C standard.

> **§6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**
>
> (5) The result of the logical negation operator **`!`** is 0 if the value of its
>   operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares
>   equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression **`!E`** is equivalent
>   to **`(0==E)`**.
>
> **§6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> (3) An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type **`void *`**, is called a *null pointer constant*. <sup>66</sup>) If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.
>
> (6) Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously speciﬁed, the result is implementation-deﬁned. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.
>
> Footnotes: <sup>66</sup> The macro **`NULL`** is deﬁned in **<stddef.h>** (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.

As you can see, 0 is kind of a magic number in C.  For systems with a non-zero `NULL`, I expect that the actual behaviour of `!msize` may be implementation-defined.  In any case, this is all a bit nit-picky.

I tracked down the source of your example in the paper: [Undeﬁned Behavior: What Happened to My Code?](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/ub%3aapsys12.pdf).  The text discussing your example states:

> As mentioned earlier, at the instruction set level, x86 raises an
>   exception for a division by zero [17, 3.2], while MIPS [22, A.6] and
>   PowerPC [15, 3.3.38] silently ignore it. A division by zero in C is
>   undefined behavior [19, 6.5.5], and a compiler can thus simply assume
>   that the divisor is always non-zero.
>
> Figure 1 shows a division-by-zero misuse in the Linux kernel. From the
>   programmer’s comment it is clear that the intention is to signal an
>   error in case msize is zero. When compiling with GCC, this code
>   behaves as intended on an x86, but not on a PowerPC, because it will
>   not generate an exception. When compiling with Clang, the result is
>   even more surprising. Clang assumes that the divisor msize must be
>   non-zero—on any system—since otherwise the division is undefined.
>   Combined with this assumption, the zero check !msize becomes always
>   false, since msize cannot be both zero and non-zero. The compiler
>   determines that the whole block of code is unreachable and removes it,
>   which has the unexpected effect of removing the programmer’s original
>   intention of guarding against the case when msize is zero.

So in your case, the answer you really needed was yes: it tests whether `msize` is 0.

Comment: Not to mention `NULL` is `0`.

Comment: @Michał While it may be on your compiler, that is not necessarily true.

Comment: `NULL` is a macro and is not used in an expression like `!msize` which is simply equivalent to `msize == 0`, be `msize` an object of an arithmetic or pointer type.

Comment: @ouah I'm certain that I've seen part of the C standard specifically talk about this distinction before.  I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments and the help. It was really helpful.